# Which items are checkMarked in my CheckListBox (from the top of the list)?

Tags: vb.net, windows, winforms, checklistbox

In VB.NET, I can easily use CheckedItems to see that 3 elements are checkMarked in my CheckListBox.
I loop through 0,1,2 and correctly get the text on each line that is checkMarked.
(With only a small/quick loop of 0-2)

But how can I determine those 3 elements are on lines 14,222,1255?
(Without looping through 1000s of items.)

Thanks

Comment: Firstly, have you proven that looping over thousands of items performs poorly enough that you need a different approach? Plus you are probably going to have bigger issues if you try and put thousands of controls on a single form.

Comment: You would use the `CheckedIndices` property instead of `CheckedItems`, which you should know because you should have used the Help menu in VS to open the MSDN documentation and read about the `CheckedListBox` class before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CheckedIndices` instead. They'll give you directly line numbers.